# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

Can you please help me on this error

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException:
>   Transaction is already completed - do not call commit or rollback more
>   than once per transaction

Code

```
@Override
    public String saveTemplatesToPCA(List<FilesTemplateDomain> fileTemplates) {
         TransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
         TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);
        try {
            template.saveOrUpdateAll(fileTemplates);
            transactionManager.commit(status);

            return "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transactionManager.rollback(status);
            System.out.println("Exception in saveTemplatesToPCA() : "+e);
            return "fail";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if transaction is autocommited? Do not call commit or rollback more than once per transaction.

Comment: sorry i can't understand..!

Comment: @nikpon rollback and commit was necessary in my case, so I handle this exceptioo.. now fine thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle this Exception

```
@Override
    public String saveTemplatesToPCA(List<FilesTemplateDomain> fileTemplates) {
         TransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
         TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);
        try {
            template.saveOrUpdateAll(fileTemplates);
            transactionManager.commit(status);

            return "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try{
            transactionManager.rollback(status);
            }catch(Exception ee){
                System.out.println("Exception in commit or rollback : "+ee);
            }
            System.out.println("Exception in saveTemplatesToPCA() : "+e);
            return "fail";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to @nikpon.. I have to handle transaction rollback method in my catch block also...

Comment: thanks to you I can see the error of the rollback and that turn debug much easier ;)

Comment: What if you want to update another record in another nested transaction?